# TFS stopwatch task tracking system

Tags: .net, tfs, desktop-application, ontime

My company is starting using TFS Team Foundation Server, for bug and task tracking system, I used OnTime before.
At the OnTime they had a tool called OnTime StopWatch, you could download the tool and use a desktop application that you could start and pause a specific task progress, and when you finished it you could just click update tasks and it would update to you from your desktop to your task server.

In TFS there is no out of the box application, as you can see at this thread.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-BE/tfsgeneral/thread/80cd2fb9-1d70-49a0-8197-1cce137de3b3

Is there any add-in or desktop application I can use with TFS that works like the OnTime StopWatch ?
Some people was thinking about build one in here using .Net for desktop application, but I think it would take too much time for a developer to make it, since there isn't nothing on the market till the moment.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new feature in Visual Studio 11 called "my work", that looks like what you described.

Check [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/09/19/the-new-team-explorer-in-tfs-11.aspx), in the meantime I'm not sure you'll find what you need.

Btw, such application wouldn't be so hard to develop with the TFS API...